# Apple Review Guidelines - Title of publication or service

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Apple rejected my app because it doesn't have a *"Title of publication or service"*.

I have been googling for the past 2 hours and cannot find an example or a definition for this. How do i add this to my app ? is it just like terms and conditions or is it a widget or some kind?
I built the app in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you offer auto-renewing subcriptions? This wording seems very much like the one cited [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/70917) as part of Schedule 2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement:

> You clearly and conspicuously disclose to users the following
> information regarding Your auto-renewing subscription:
>
> - Title of publication or service
> - Length of subscription (time period and/or content/services provided during each subscription period)

So it seems that Apple wants you to be more precise in describing the subscriptions you offer.
You can review the license agreement in [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com) under `Agreements, Tax and Banking`

Comment: Ok so i just need to create a button much like privacy policy that clearly outlines the details of auto-renewal ?

Comment: Maybe, but it could be that your in app product descriptions need to be clearer. "Premium access" is not a good description. "1 month of premium content with no ads" is a good description.